# Text orientation to top in a NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, swift, storyboard, nsoutlineview

i've got a NSOutlineView to display and edit key value pairs. If the value wraps around, than the key is centred vertically.
I want to have both texts starts in the first line.

[image]

How to put them to top? Either in Code oder in the Storyboard. 
Thank you for any hint.

***UPDATE***
This is the rendering code, maybe i have to add a NSLayoutConstraint? Can you give me an example?

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView,
    heightOfRowByItem item: AnyObject) -> CGFloat {
        let node = item as JSONDataNode
        let col: NSTableColumn = outlineView.outlineTableColumn!
        let cell: NSCell = col.dataCell as NSCell
        cell.stringValue = node.getString()
        let height = cell.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, col.width, 1000.0)).height
        return height
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {

    let node = item as JSONDataNode

    var cell = NSTableCellView()

    if tableColumn?.identifier == "NAME_COLUMN" {
        cell = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("NAME_COLUMN", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
        cell.textField!.stringValue = node.key
        cell.textField!.editable = true
        cell.textField!.delegate = self

    } else
        if tableColumn?.identifier == "VALUE_COLUMN" {
            cell = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("VALUE_COLUMN", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
            cell.textField!.stringValue = node.getString()
            cell.textField!.editable = true
            cell.textField!.delegate = self
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a

```
outlineView.rowSizeStyle    =   NSTableViewRowSizeStyle.Small
```

in my viewDidLoad that do the trick. After i removed this line the text will show up at the top of the row.

The documentation says:

```
The table will use a row height specified for a small table. It is     
required that the size be fully tested and supported if 
NSTableViewRowSizeStyleCustom is not used.
```

hmm, 'mkay.